# Phone gets extra hot and connection problems with replacement ROM

Tags: connection-issues, sim-card, system-error

Ever since I upgraded my Galaxy S4 to Lollipop (CM12.1) I have had problems with the SIM card 'being removed'. It usually happens after a bit of use and the phone gets hot. I get a 'SIM card has been removed, please restart' error and I cannot connect to my carrier until I do (Wi-Fi and Bluetooth still work, as well as the SD card reader). I have tried an upgrade to Marshmallow (CM13) but the fault remains as well as inducing Bluetooth problems so I have rolled back to Lollipop. I have also tried replacing the SIM and SD card holder with no change.

I'm wondering if there was some power management Samsung had in their ROM that CyanogenMod hasn't implemented.

Is there a way to control the power consumption so the phone doesn't get too hot and possibly cause problems with the SIM card holder?

Comment: Flashing the stock firmware should solve the issue.

Comment: That would mean rolling back to Jellybean. I'm hoping to avoid that. But if I did, is that stored internally or will I need to find a Samsung ROM online?

Comment: The custom ROM often are full of bugs, you should know that. If the issue is not hardware related, flashing the stock firmware should resolve that. No you have yo download online.

Comment: Have you gotten a replacement SIM card from your carrier? Also, try removing the SIM and putting a layer or two of scotch tape on the back side and reinsert it, might help maintain the connection.

Comment: I have tried a new SIM and padding the card in the slot with no effect.

Comment: So far, I can only find *.tar.md5 ROMS which TWRP does not recognise and fails to install.